# Bigquery: new column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following table structure

```
+----+-------------+------------+
| id | transaction |    time    |
+----+-------------+------------+
|  1 |          10 | 01.01.2018 |
|  1 |          20 | 10.01.2018 |
|  2 |          20 | 05.01.2018 |
|  2 |          30 | 15.01.2018 |
|  2 |           5 | 03.02.2018 |
+----+-------------+------------+
```

What I want to do now, is to calculate the sum of transaction for each id. However, I would like to do it with a rolling sum for each let's say month of time separately. So I would like to end with something like:

```
+----+-------+-------+
| id | sum_1 | sum_2 |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 |    30 |    30 |
|  2 |    50 |    55 |
+----+-------+-------+
```

So that means, I would like to group time monthly, and calculate the sum for each id up to this point. So it's not like a classic partition I assume. Of course I could just do it separately and then join, but as I have quite many monthly or maybe weekly partitions, this might not be feasible. Maybe someone has an idea.

Comment: Are you looking for a query that will give you the result you posted? Or a generic query that will also potentially allow you to partition by week or some other time period? Because you seem to have asked both things here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 10 transaction, '01.01.2018' time UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 20, '10.01.2018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 20, '05.01.2018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 30, '15.01.2018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 5, '03.02.2018' 
)
SELECT id, month, 
  SUM(transactions) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY month) rolling_transactions
FROM (
  SELECT id, 
    DATE_TRUNC(PARSE_DATE('%d.%m.%Y', time), MONTH) month,
    SUM(transaction) transactions
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY id, month 
)
ORDER BY id, month
```

with result as

```sql
Row id  month       rolling_transactions     
1   1   2018-01-01  30   
2   2   2018-01-01  50   
3   2   2018-02-01  55
```

It is more recommended to have flatten result as it scales to any number of months or weeks or whatever else time period you need and then you can further pivot result in your application

Note: for weekly case  - just change MONTH to WEEK in DATE_TRUNC